# loader inside the kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel, system-calls

Assuming I don't care about security, the goal is to write a new system call that given a binary (ELF) can execute it inside the kernel.

Let's say I have a *statically compiled* binary `A` whose location in memory is `ptr_A`, the goal is to instrument the kernel with a new system call

`sys_new_loader(ptr_A, ptr_result)`

that

1. *executes* A *inside the kernel*, that is it is not possible for user space program to peek into *A*
2. returns value at location specified by `ptr_result` .

How could I go about implement this?

(I understand that `exec` system call family does a lot of book-keeping before transfering the control to user space. Do I need all those book-keeping, or can I simply jump to the specific location in `ptr_A`)

Comment: can't you do that by replacing your binary with a kernel module?